# Is redirecting (for roles specific content) in a REST API a good idea?

Tags: api, rest, restful-architecture, restful-url, hateoas

Lets imagine we have a resource URL `/course/{id}` in a REST based API. We also have two different roles: `user` and `member`. A `user` is just a normal user and a `member` is a user who has subscribed for a specific course.

A `course` has some public information (like name or description) visible for all `user` and some additional private information only visible for a `member` of the course.

I have decided to prefix all `member` specific content with "member". So the URL for a `member` would be `/member/courses/{id}` which shows the public and private information.

---

In short:

URL (only for role `member`): `/member/courses/{id}` => return public and private information

URL (for all):  `/courses/{id}` => return public information

---

If now a `member` tries to access the public site `/courses/{id}` I would like him to be redirected to the member URL.

```
HTTP/1.0 303 SEE OTHER
Location: /member/courses/{id}
```

Is that RESTfull? Or is it better (while following HATEOAS) to provide for resources for which a user is NOT a `member` only the URL `/courses/{id}` and for resource for which a user is a `member` provide the URL `/member/courses/{id}`?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound too RESTful indeed, I think you'd be better off with the latter approach, building the relationship URLs depending on the user class (since you've already decided on the URL and not displaying that private information is out of the question).

Alternatively you might've split that "private information" into a separate entity, and just control the access policy for it - unless it doesn't really make sense to split it from a business/domain point of view.